# Combining Two Tables In Symfony and Doctrine With Query?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have the following query that I a running in symfony, I would like to fetch each video and then the channel information that goes with that video.

> 'SELECT v, c FROM AppBundle:Videos v, AppBundle:Channels c WHERE v.videoPublisherId = c.channelId  ORDER BY v.id DESC'

and it is outputting the following

[image]

The problem is that I would like the results combined into 1 object "row" instead of a video object and and then a channel object. I usually use MYSQL and it would output as I need it. Could someone point me in the right direction thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a relation you can try with a JOIN, here you're selected two entities so there is two rows.
try Something like that :

```
'SELECT v FROM AppBundle:Videos v JOIN AppBundle:Channels c WHERE v.videoPublisherId = c.channelId ORDER BY v.id DESC'
```